# Control several Browsers with Applescript

Tags: browser, applescript

Is there any way to control 2 different safari browser windows with Applescript at the same time und switch between them? Something like a unique ID to be sure which commands are for which safari window.

something like...

```
tell application "Safari" id 1
    activate
    ....
end tell
```

:-)

thanks for your help.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows in AppleScript are code objects, so if you make a reference to one, e.g.:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set aWindow to window 1 -- sets a reference to the current front window
end tell
```

AppleScript will remember that particular window even if you move it, hide it, put it in the background, minimize it... Until you reset the variable or close the window, you can be sure that aWindow will point to that particular window. In fact, this works the same for tabs. You can say:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set aTab to tab 3 of window 1 -- sets a reference to the third tab of the current front window
end tell
```

and even if you move that tab to a different window, AppleScript should still track it. Likewise, if you have a window pointing to the Google Search engine, you can say:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set aWindow to window "Google" -- sets a reference to the Google window
end tell
```

and then if you navigate to a different webpage, the variable aWindow will still point at the same window. Neat, huh?

So all you need to do is create a couple of variables for your two windows, and you can switch back and forth as you like:

```
tell application "Safari"
    -- assuming you have a 'Google' window and a 'Yahoo' window open
    set firstWindow to window "Google"
    set secondWindow to window "Yahoo"
    set URL of document of firstWindow to "https://stackoverflow.com"
    set index of secondWindow to 1
    set miniaturized of firstWindow to true
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows are identified by their absolute Id. You can see ID's with :

```
tell application "Safari" to set myWindow to every window
```

It gives you list of all open windows of Safari like :{window id 4519, window id 4426, window id 4514}. There are 3 open windows !

However to switch between 2 Safari windows, you must use their number: 1 is the frontmost, 2 is behind, 3 is behind the 2,...
You can tell the System Events to make number 2 before number 1. Doing so, old 2 becomes 1 and the 1 becomes 2.

```
tell application "System Events" to perform action "AXRaise" of window 2 of process "Safari"
```

if you just have 2 windows, the line above will keep switching between your 2 Safari windows, each time making the second window the frontmost one.

Comment: _"However to switch between 2 Safari windows, you must use their number"_ This isn't correct, as Ted demonstrates in his answer.  The use of _System Events_ here is also unnecessary.